# Adafruit 16x2 RGB LCD scrolling down?

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio

So I'm working on a little project to show a fortune on this 16x2 LCD. I've been successful so far, but when it came to longer fortunes, it would just cut off. How would I go about scrolling downwards to show the entire fortune? There are absolutely no functions as to scroll downwards. Scrolling left or right will not really work.

Comment: What if you rotate the text 90 degrees, and then physically rotate the LED panel 90 degrees. Then left/right will be up/down ?

Comment: Yeah, but the LED panel is too thin for that. It's 16x2. Here's a pic: afruit.com/assets/2620

Comment: Do you mean, it doesn't fit on one line, or it doesn't fit on 2 lines?